# Custom AuthenticationProvider with extra login fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a customAuthenticationProvider and I want to authenticate user with 3 parameters: username, password and tokenPin.
But at the moment I have a little problem with this provider:

```
@Component 
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {


@Autowired
private UserService userService;


@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    String pin = ????

    Authentication auth = null;

    User user = userService.findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password);

    if (user != null) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, grantedAuths);
    }


    return auth;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

}

Comment: Use your own `Authentication` object don't abuse the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` for that. You will also need a custom filter to populate that custom `Authentication` object.

Comment: may be you are looking for [this](http://naeemgik.blogspot.com/2018/10/passing-extra-login-fields-with-spring.html)